# notifyDataSetChanged(); for update list. When i typed in TextView the list is not change

Tags: android, android-layout

I created one adapter and i used Google Places API to show address.

I called `notifyDataSetChanged();` to update the list.

But When i typed in `TextView` the list is not changed.

### Adapter

```
    adapter = new SelectAddressAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, addressList);      
    addressListView.setAdapter(adapter);

   addresseEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

               @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                    GoogleAPIRequestHandler handler = new GoogleAPIRequestHandler();

                    String date= handler.execute(input).get();
                    addressList = new ArrayList<AddressList>();
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(date);

                    JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");
                        for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        AddressList a = new AddressList();
                        String addressJson = predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString();
                        a.Deserialize(addressJson);
                        addressList.add(a);
        }        
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();;
```

Comment: Every time you creating new array List please check your code

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        AddressList a = new AddressList();
                        String addressJson = predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString();
                        a.Deserialize(addressJson);
                        addressList.add(a);
```

To

```
for (int i = 0; i <= predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                      if(i<predsJsonArray.length())
                       {
                        AddressList a = new AddressList();
                        String addressJson = predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString();
                        a.Deserialize(addressJson);
                        addressList.add(a);
                     }
else
{
              adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement methods of TextWatcher within you need to add the runOnUiThread method

```
       addresseEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {                       

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                GoogleAPIRequestHandler handler = new GoogleAPIRequestHandler();

                String date= handler.execute(input).get();
                addressList = new ArrayList<AddressList>();
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(date);

                JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");
                    for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    AddressList a = new AddressList();
                    String addressJson = predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString();
                    a.Deserialize(addressJson);
                    addressList.add(a);
    }        
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    } 
   }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

- ```
  private  void setAddressRecyclerView()   {
   adapter = new SelectAddressAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, addressList);
   addressListView.setAdapter(adapter);   }
  ```
- ```
  private  void updateAddressList(ArrayList<String> updatedAddressList)   {
   this.addressList=updatedAddressList;notifyDataSetChanged(); }
  ```
- ```
  private  void edtAddressTextWatcher()   {
   addresseEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence,  int i,
                                     int i1,
                                     int i2){}
       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence,
                                 int i,
                                 int i1,
                                 int i2)
       {
           try {
               getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
                   if (adapter != null &&
                           addressList != null &&
                           addressList.size() > 0)
                   {
                       String input = charSequence.toString();
                       if (input.length() > 0)
                       {
                           Log.w(TAG, "TextWatcher-------" + charSequence);
                           GoogleAPIRequestHandler handler = new
                                   GoogleAPIRequestHandler();

                           String date= handler.execute(input).get();
                           addressList = new ArrayList<AddressList>();
                           JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(date);

                           JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");
                           for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++)  {
                               AddressList a = new AddressList();
                               String addressJson = predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString();
                               a.Deserialize(addressJson);
                               addressList.add(a);
                           }
                           adapter.updateAddressList(addressList);

                       }

                   }
               });
           } catch (Exception e) {
               Log.e(TAG, "Error----TextWatcher----onTextChanged()---" + charSequence.toString());
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}
   });
  ```

Comment: Please add some details on how your answer address the question.